# Using formal power series.

Tags: ring-theory

Suppose $R$ is a commutative ring (with or without $1$), and for $a_0,...,a_m,b_0,...,b_m\in R$ and for all $0\le k\le m$ we have
$$a_0b_k+a_1b_{k-1}+\dots+a_kb_0=0 $$
then there's some nonzero $r\in R$,
$$ra_0=\dots =ra_m=0 \quad \text{ or }\quad rb_0=...=rb_m=0$$

Do formal power series provide a simple proof for this?

Comment: I don't think this is true without additional assumptions- consider $a_i=1,b_j=0$ for all suitable $i,j$.

Comment: @KReiser: thanks.